# AppHarbor Isn't overwriting my local RavenDB entry

Tags: ravendb, appharbor

When I publish my app to appHarbor, I receive the following errors when I visit my app page and disable custom errors. It's complaining about lines in the Web.config file:

`the entry ravendb has already been added`

It's annoying to have to go in and "prep" my web.config and app.config each time I publush. Isn't it supposed to over-write whatever values I put in there?

Comment: Probably best to contact AppHarbor support

Comment: Where are you getting this error?